# How to Avoid redeeming Google Authorization Code every time

Tags: google-drive-api, authorization, token

```
    public class image {
    private String applicationName;

    public image setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
          this.applicationName = applicationName;
          return this;
        }
      private static String CLIENT_ID = "***";
      private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "***";
      private static String REDIRECT_URI = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();


        String code = "4/-4JsvGiqNpZ6Ms5dLjLA2QgzgToGAxx_SZTeByBPh_Q";

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        .build()
        .setFromTokenResponse(response);

        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
        .setApplicationName("musik")
        .build();

        //Insert a file  
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("My document");
        body.setDescription("A test document");
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
    }

}
```

I am trying to upload file on my drive using Drive Api, everything is working fine except I have to redeem the Google Authorization code every time after using it.
Is there any tweak or method for the above code to not redeem I every time by using any refresh token or access token method?

Answer (score 1):

You need not redeem authorization code every time. You get the authorization code and then refresh and access token once you are authenticated. So Instead you can use refresh token to refresh the access token and then do google drive operations.

Content body should be in this format "**client_id=[clientId]&client_secret=[clientSecret]&refresh_token=[RefreshToken]&grant_type=refresh_token**" and do a HTTP post method to refresh the access token.

Comment: Suhas can u tweak the above code to illustrate the concept?